# What causes this code not to compile correctly

Tags: java

Im building a program to round to two decimal places. The user types in a float that they what rounded and it returns that double rounded to the nearest two decimal places. Theres no errors in the code but after compiling the code returns 0.0. Greatly appreciate the help!

```java
package Exercises;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Rounding {
    float precise;
    
    float Precision(float f){
        f = precise;
        precise = (float) Math.round(f*100)/100;
        return precise;
    }
}

public class Round {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float originalfloat, roundedfloat;
        
        System.out.println(" Type in float number");
        Scanner type = new Scanner(System.in);
        originalfloat = type.nextFloat();
        
        Rounding ro = new Rounding();
        roundedfloat = ro.Precision(originalfloat);
        
        System.out.println(" Original float number :" + originalfloat);
        
        System.out.println();
        
        System.out.println("Rounded float number " + roundedfloat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is: why does this code not compile correctly? then you state: " Theres no errors in the code but after compiling the code returns 0.0". It compiles correctly, you just made a mistake in your code.

Comment: Your title claims the code is not compiling correctly... I see no indication of that. I see unexpected behavior at execution time, but that's not really the same thing. It would also really help if you could hard code sample values and show the output, rather than relying on user input (and then not telling us what value you're using).

Comment: And this code does not *return* anything, if anything it outputs something on stdout. What is the input, what is the exact actual output, what is the exact expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this part:

```java
    float Precision(float f){
        f = precise;
        precise = (float) Math.round(f*100)/100;
        return precise;
    }
```

When you instantiate a `Rounding` object here:

```java
Rounding ro = new Rounding();
```

you initialize `precise` to `0`, because that's what Java does when you don't explicitly initialize primitive numeric types:

```java
float precise;
```

One you instantiate `Precision` with a value, you are replacing it with the contents of `precise`, which has been initialized to `0`:

```java
    float Precision(float f){
        f = precise; // <-- right here, 'f' becomes zero
        precise = (float) Math.round(f*100)/100;
        return precise;
    }
```

Since `f` is now `0`, `Math.round(f*100)/100` will also be `0`, and thus the result of the function is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line: `f = precise;` because you dont use given parameter named f then. You just use default value of precise which is 0.0.

```
float preciseNumber(float f){
    precise = (float) Math.round(f * 100)/100;
    return precise;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would change this line

```
precise = (float) Math.round(f*100)/100;
```

With this line

```
precise = (float) Math.floor(f*100)/100;
```

Comment: It will not help, he has bug in code.

Comment: That simply changes the rounding mechanic to always round down, does not *fix* anything.